# React-native Cannot connect to development server

Tags: react-native

I have been successfully developing my react native app using the development server for the past two weeks. However, as of this morning, I am no longer able to connect the device and load the application by running

```
react-native run-android
```

A few details about the package versions...

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.3.1",
  "react-native": "0.55.4",
  "react-native-camera": "^1.1.4",
  "react-native-fs": "^2.10.14",
  "react-native-video": "^2.2.0",
  "react-navigation": "^2.2.0"
}
```

What I have tried so far.

0) Make sure that the dev settings are directed towards the correct local ip and port

```
Debug server host & port for device: 192.168.0.9:8081
```

1) Clean the android project

I have used both the Android Studio gui and

```
/home/user/project/android/.gradlew clean
```

2) Ensure the package server is running. I start it with

```
react-native start
```

I then check that it started successfully with

```
curl http://192.168.0.9:8081/ | grep packager
```

and get

```
...<p>React Native packager is running.</p>...
```

I can even go to the url that the app is trying to access and get a valid response

```
curl http://192.168.0.9:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false 

var __DEV__=true,__BUNDLE_START_TIME__=this.nativePerformanceNow?nativePerformanceNow()...
```

3) Run the application through an emulator.

If I start an android emulator through studio I am able to successfully launch the application with

```
react-native run-android
```

4) Restart the mobile and development devices.

I have also tried accessing the development server from other devices through a web browser and am still unable to view the page as I can from the development machine. This would lead me to believe that this is some sort of firewall issue. Any help is greatly appreciated!

*Note - adb reverse is not available since I'm on android 4.4.2 :(

Comment: Which os?if `windows`, try to disable the firewall and try again

Comment: @MohamadKh75 ubuntu 16.04

Comment: As you mentioned that you can't access the url from browser, try to add `8081` port to your allowed firewall list and try again!

Comment: Well, I took a nice walk, came back and tried again - whala, it works. No changes to the firewall were necessary. I will explore and try to reproduce the error.